# R: Exporting nested list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, nested-lists, janitor

I have created a nested list of data frames using the tabyl function in janitory and lapply. As the tabyl function with three variables returns a list of dataframes,  using lapply results in a nested list. In this case I am looking at different variables across democratic performance and regions. The result looks something like this:

```
    $ Freedom of Expression
    ..$ Africa (tabyl)
    ..$ Asia (tabyl)
    ..$ Europe (tabyl)
    $ Freedom of Movement
    ..$ Africa (tabyl)
    ..$ Asia (tabyl)
    ..$ Europe (tabyl)
```

With each region having a data frame that looks like this:

```
regime      High Freedom of Expression  Low Freedom of Expression   Mid-Range Freedom of Expression     Total
Democracy   100.0% (1)          0.0% (0)            70.0% (21)              44.9% (22)
Hybrid Regime   0.0% (0)            38.9%(7)            30.0%  (9)              32.7% (16)
Non-Democratic Regime 0.0% (0)          61.1% (11)              0.0%  (0)               22.4% (11)
```

I would like to export this to a .csv or a text file in order to share with people who don't know how to use R.

I have tried using the flatten function from purrr, however this results in a list of regions, but with crosstabs from only one of the variables. I have also used the list.flatten from the rlist package, but it ends up returning every row of the data frame as a separate element in a list.

Thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `map(bind_rows)` (at depth 1), followed by a second `bind_rows`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test

lapply(
  replicate(2, mtcars, simplify = FALSE),
  tabyl, cyl, gear, am
) %>% 
  map(bind_rows, .id = "region") %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "freedom_of")
#>  freedom_of region cyl  3 4 5
#>           1      0   4  1 2 0
#>           1      0   6  2 2 0
#>           1      0   8 12 0 0
#>           1      1   4  0 6 2
#>           1      1   6  0 2 1
#>           1      1   8  0 0 2
#>           2      0   4  1 2 0
#>           2      0   6  2 2 0
#>           2      0   8 12 0 0
#>           2      1   4  0 6 2
#>           2      1   6  0 2 1
#>           2      1   8  0 0 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>